# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 fir React Front End/Rails Backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, npm

I get this error message when I run npm start:

```
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! quote-react-redux@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the quote-react-redux@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Anyone have an idea of what is going on? Or is there any documentation to read npm error logs as well?

Comment: you're trying to `map` over a variable that you are expecting to be an Array but instead it's `undefined`. Share some more code and we will be able to help you

Comment: How does NPM factor into this? How could we reproduce this problem?

Comment: What is this `quote-react-redux` library? I don't see it on NPM.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten similar errors, ie. to reproduce one of mine:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 develop: `gatsby develop`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 develop script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The problem occurs when I am running a different version of `node` than the one I used to either generate the app with, or perhaps was cloned from elsewhere and forgot to run `npm install`.

Fix 1: Change the node version to the same version the app was generated with in the directory you are trying to launch the server via your node version manager.

Fix 2: Make sure you have the node version you want to run set in the directory you are working in, then `npm install`. You may want to do this in an new git branch, until you get it running, then merge into master, as sometimes if the versions were really different you may need to manually install additional packages (they will be listed).

Fix 3: Clear out and start from scratch (probably better than Fix 2). Try:

```
npm cache clean --force
rm package-lock.json
/bin/rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```